# python- проблемы с кодировкой при считывании из mysql БД и записи обратно

Tags: mysql, python, python-3.x, кодировка, utf-8

Пытаюсь делать это вот так Текст комментов и оценки формируют Dataframe,  который потом я записываю  в другую таблицу :

```
db_connection = 'mysql+pymysql://root@localhost/mom_db'
conn = create_engine(db_connection, encoding='utf-8')

test = pd.read_sql("SELECT comm FROM comments ", conn)

test['comm'] = test['comm'].apply(delete_tabs)
print(test['comm'])
#test['expected'] = [-1, -1, 1, 1]
test['pred_lr'] = grid_lr.best_estimator_.predict(test['comm'])
test['pred_nb'] = grid_nb.best_estimator_.predict(test['comm'])
pd.options.display.expand_frame_repr = False
test.to_sql(name='est_comm', con=conn, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

На выходе получаю:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u0418' in position 2: ordinal not in range(256)
```

перепробовал уже очень много всего. И в Apache-2.4-x64_server.conf строчки дописывал, и различным образом пытался указать кодировку в самом скритпе. ничего не помогло.

Comment: Так пробовали: `db_connection = 'mysql+pymysql://root@localhost/mom_db?charset=utf8'`?

Comment: стоп, не увидел отличия, сейчас попробую

Comment: ДА, заработало!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте `charset=utf8`:

```
db_connection = 'mysql+pymysql://root@localhost/mom_db?charset=utf8'
#   ---->                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
conn = create_engine(db_connection, encoding='utf-8')
```